# symfony get data from db in while loop

Tags: symfony, while-loop, doctrine

I need to grab data from a symfony 2 db. The data looks like :

```
Parent-Element [id 15]
 -> Child Element [id 20, parent ID 15]
 --->Child Element [id 27, parent ID 20]
 ----->Child Element [id 34, Parent ID 27]
 ....
```

The Childs are assigned to each parent Element by a cathegory ID see [ ].
There might be more than one Child Elements per level.

In php it would be easy to grab this by a while loop. But in Symfony im stucking. Can anyone help me finding a solution? IS there a while loop in symfony?

Kind regdards

Philipp

EDIT: I mean, in "normal" php I would do a simple while or create an array with ids which I loop through by another while loop... In smyfony, I would use a queryBuilder like that

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('d')
    ->from('PrUserBundle:Location', 'd')
    ->where('d.client_id = :client_id')
    ->setParameter('client_id', $this->clientId)
    ->getQuery();
    $results=$query->getResult();
```

Where I don't see any possibility to grab any other Ids or sort it so that I can render a parent-child listing.

Comment: Uhm, Symfony *is* PHP, you can use while loops all you want. Could it be that your question is rather aimed at the difference between retrieving results in plain MySQL and retrieving results in Doctrine/DQL? If so, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```